# How do I fix an incorrect Timezone Offset in Java 1.5.0?

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a program that uses `java.util.TimeZone` to produce the GMT offsets for various timezones.  Recently it was pointed out that one of the timezones was off by an hour, Argentina Buenos Aires.

I wrote a simple java program to see what the java `TimeZone` class was giving as the offset.  It turns out it was giving the wrong value for Buenos Aires but all the other timezones (that we use) were ok.  I think the problem might be the java version on the machine that runs the code.  One machine (v1.6.0_22) gives the correct value the other (v1.5.0) gives the incorrect value.  Has anyone else had an issue like this, or have a different explination for the differences in offset values?  Here is the test program I used:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TZTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Java version = "+ System.getProperty("java.version"));

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();

    System.out.println("Current System Time is: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    System.out.println("Current Calendar Time is: " + new Date(now.getTimeInMillis()));
    System.out.println("Current TimeZone is: \"" + timeZone.getDisplayName() + "\": ID = " + timeZone.getID());

    //One ID for the timezone in question
    String id = "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires";
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
    System.out.println("\ntimeZone.getTimeZone(ID) using ID = \""+ id + "\" returns\n" + TimeZone.getTimeZone(id));
    System.out.println("Offset in hours: "+(tz.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())/new Double(3600000)));

    //A second ID for the timezone in question
    String id2 = "America/Buenos_Aires";
    TimeZone tz2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id2);
    System.out.println("\ntimeZone.getTimeZone(ID2) using ID2 = \""+ id2 + "\" returns\n" + TimeZone.getTimeZone(id2));
    System.out.println("Offset in hours: "+(tz2.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())/new Double(3600000)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Built-in Java time/date stuff is notoriously broken and hard to use. I would _highly_ recommend you switch to the JodaTime library for _all_ time/date related needs.

Comment: @cdeszaq Of course, when time rules change, you can update Joda without changing your JRE version.  This is another great benefit.  +1 to your comment.

Comment: Alright thanks guys, I will likely look at Joda.  Being dependant on the java version is less then ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

each java release includes its own timezone database (this is documented in the release notes for each version).  1.5.0 is *very* old, and presumably has out of date or incorrect information for the timezone you are looking at.

Comment: Indeed, it's surely giving a time zone with daylight savings, which that country doesn't have, at least this Summer. Also, Java 5 has reached EOL so it's really recommended to move on to Java 6 (1.6.0_30 being the last version at the time of this writing)